# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: rviz, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/**init**.py", line 307, in main
p.start()

File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
self._start_infrastructure()

File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 217, in _start_infrastructure
self._load_config()

File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 132, in _load_config
roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)

File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 451, in load_config_default
loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)

File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 746, in load
self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)

File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 718, in _load_launch
self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)

File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 662, in _recurse_load
self._param_tag(tag, context, ros_config, verbose=verbose)

File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
return f(*args, **kwds)

File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 264, in _param_tag
value = self.param_value(verbose, name, ptype, *vals)

File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/loader.py", line 489, in param_value
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
errread, errwrite)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception

**OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied**

**I created a basic urdf model as mentioned in the tutorials and wrote a launch file to view the urdf in rviz
When i try to launch file using roslauch i get this error**

```
<launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264235/oserror:-%5Berrno-13%5D-permission-denied/) by [Yogi_4](https://answers.ros.org/users/30338/yogi_4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-06-20**:
Some context is needed for people to help. Please see the guidelines for asking a question [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29).

**Comment by [Yogi_4](https://answers.ros.org/users/30338/yogi_4/) on 2017-06-20**:
I have updated my question.Thank you!

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-20**:
Please also post the launch file (and format it with the `0101` button) and tell us which OS and version of ROS you have.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-21**:
@Yogi_4: I don't see an answer to your problem here, but you have closed the question. If you've solved it by yourself, please post an answer telling us what you did and accept that. If you haven't solved it, then I don't think you should close it as *answered*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@ufr3c_tjc I have deleted the package and created the same again.I have re-written the same launch file and it worked.

---

Originally posted by [Yogi_4](https://answers.ros.org/users/30338/yogi_4/) with karma: 38 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0